# MacBook pro is stuck booting indefinitely after updating to Monterey

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, software-update, monterey

**Setup**

2017 MacBook Pro 13" Model A1706 EMC 3163 No T2 Chip i5-7267UCPU @ 3.10GHz

**Problem**

After updating to Monterey, the mac was stuck on the black loading screen with the apple icon on it. I restarted it and let it load for another couple hours but nothing happened.

**What I've Tried**

Reinstalling MacOS;

> Didn't Fix it just made it worse to the point where I couldn't load recovery as there was
> no Volumes/Profiles to Recover

Internet Recovery;

> Worked and allowed me to boot safe mode but still the same result of an indefinite boot screen

Safe Mode;

> I was able to create a new account, however, safe mode takes 2 or more
> minutes to register any button clicks or whatever I type and is stuck
> on creating an account screen.

Resetting NVRAM, PRAM and SMC;

> Did nothing at all

Restarting The Mac;

> Somehow made it worse? the background screen is now pitch black and the outlines are light blue and the mouse cursor has turned into a .png, blocking some of the background wherever it goes.

Start up from Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnostics;

> Says there's nothing wrong

**What I'm able to do**

Launch in Single User Mode

**What leads to infinite boot**

Normal Start

Verbose Mode

Exiting Via Single User Mode

Starting up in target disk mode

Any type of booting other than safe mode

**New Solution?**

Connect my old mac to the one with the issues

**Worst Case Scenario**

Using my time machine backup from 2 years ago somehow

Comment: If your Mac boots to target disk  mode, you might want to do a backup before proceeding. That also may help with the path forward. Does your McBook have a T2 chip? Editing the marketing year / CPU type precise model would let us answer other than “call apple”

Comment: @bmike ah sorry I forgot to add that info. Added it now.

Comment: @Sparky Can you please capture a high-speed (slow-motion) video of Verbose Boot using your iPhone or other capable camera and upload still images of each page of text so that we can examine whether there are error messages that might hint as to the cause of the hang?

Comment: Have you tried making a new volume in Disk Utility (internet recovery) and installing macOS on that volume? Then you could recover your data from that working OS if that works.

Comment: I thought about suggesting that, but it’s quite painstaking to detach and reattach a data volume but with enough space it could work! @Ezekiel I hate to suggest anything other than data recovery if the last backup is 2 years old

Comment: @bmike I was thinking a new Data volume as well and manually recovery from the old data volume.

Comment: @Ezekiel I have tried that but it still ends up loading indefinitely during boot.
Also trying to get a high quality slow motion video of it booting in verbose mode to see if that helps

Comment: @bmike Did some searching and found my old mac, any way I could use it to recover the data? It's a MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)

Comment: Search here for target disk mode. I added a link from Apple covering that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Without a T2 your options are repair data recovery (like a paid repair at apple and you bring a drive for them to make an attempt to copy off data) or target disk mode to attempt data recovery yourself or third party technician assisting.

For the repair, an [upgrade from OWC](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/aura-pro-nt) might let you get a working Mac and a sled to mount your old SSD.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac

Once you’re ready to do an erase install you will know if the hardware failed or just the filesystem was corrupt. You might try a tool like Disk Warrior or Drive Genius before the erase but after the recovery attempt.